# Does installing KDE on Ubuntu truncate support life

Tags: gnome, kde

I've just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04 because I wanted the 5 year support.  However I'm not a big Gnome fan.  I prefer KDE.  If I install KDE and purge Gnome, will I technically have Kubuntu and my 5 year support drop to 3? Thanks.

Comment: Changing the DE does not affect support. You can use any DE of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose to use KDE instead of GNOME, LTS support will not be disabled. This is true with using all other desktop environments. If you delete GNOME Desktop Environment completely (GDM3 and such would be deleted, probably to be replaced by LightDM or another display manager) LTS support will still not be disabled. LTS support is connected with your Ubuntu version, not GNOME. GNOME is simply the default window manager. Also, there is a big difference between Ubuntu running KDE and Kubuntu. Kubuntu 20.04's LTS support is available through 2023 whereas Ubuntu with KDE has LTS support through 2025, just like Ubuntu 20.04 running GNOME. For more information regarding this, see [LTS support for Kubuntu vs Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393895/lts-support-for-kubuntu-vs-ubuntu)

Also, installing KDE will not change Ubuntu to Kubuntu. It will still be Ubuntu, just using the KDE Plasma desktop environment.

One more thing: According to [https://linuxhint.com/kubuntu-vs-ubuntu/#:~:text=The%20significant%20difference%20between%20Kubuntu,doesn't%20look%20like%20Windows.](https://linuxhint.com/kubuntu-vs-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=The%20significant%20difference%20between%20Kubuntu,doesn%27t%20look%20like%20Windows.), the main difference between Ubuntu and Kubuntu is the GUI. Kubuntu is supposed to look like Windows. It also says that Kubuntu is faster than Windows. Kubuntu was designed to be more easily customized and can easily switch between interfaces. *Ubuntu*, on the other hand, is not nearly as easy to customize (and is focused on running software (freeware/third party) seamlessly along with the ease/convenience of the user, unlike Kubuntu which is oriented with look and customization instead of convenience). Just changing the DE on Ubuntu will keep the Ubuntu settings and will *not* use the settings that Kubuntu uses by default.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it clarified the difference between Ubuntu running KDE and Kubuntu -- which *does* have shorter support.

Comment: I added the information. Thanks

Comment: And then some...

Comment: I guess long answers that say the EXACT same thing are better.

Comment: Long answers that don't assume readers know what you do and therefore include explanation of *why* this is an/the answer are better.  Specifically in this case, explaining *why* Ubuntu + KDE is not the same as Kubuntu makes the answer better.

Comment: **+1** Great answer @Jeff! GNOME is **not** a [Window Manager](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) (WM). it's a [Desktop Environment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (DE). In the newer versions of GNOME ["Mutter"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutter_(software)) is the default Windows Manager and ["GDM" (GNOME Display Manager)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager) is the default display manager. Perhaps [edit] your answer and correct these terms **;-)**.

Comment: I can fix that... I always get confused with the two for some reason. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the DE does not affect support. You can use any DE of your choice.

Comment: But Kubuntu has less support than Gnome?  Must be due to other tools included in that flavor?

Comment: You are mixing OS with DE. Kubuntu is an OS Gnome is an DE.

Comment: What's not clear is how Kubuntu differs from Ubuntu with KDE installed and Gnome purged.

Comment: Again you are just looking at the DE there are many differences in the OS not just the DE. Do a Google search and compare the 2 different OS.

Comment: My point is, this would be a better answer if you clarify that.  Otherwise, you're just assuming the asker knows what you know -- and if they did, why would they ask at all?  In fact, as a one-liner, this answer is in danger of deletion.

Comment: Thanks All.  I appreciate the comments and explanations.  I was mistakenly thinking Kubuntu was simply Ubuntu shipped with KDE. With that thought in mind I figured deleting Gnome and adding KDE would convert my Ubuntu into Kubuntu and therefore limiting my support to 3 years (2023).   Thanks Again.