# Ubuntu 20.04 EOL message too early?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, kde

I am running

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

According to https://endoflife.software/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu, this is supported until April 2025. However I have a naggingg notification that is counting down the days to, it seems, 2023-04-20. It states:

[image: GUI Notification]

Other relevant info could be that I'm running KDE, here is the version info:

```
Package: kded5
Version: 5.68.0-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/libs
Source: kded
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian/Kubuntu Qt/KDE Maintainers <debian-qt-kde@lists.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
```

Any idea what might be causing this message to appear apparently two years early? Is there a danger that this might cause my laptop (that I use for all my work) to stop receiving updates?

Comment: Kubuntu 20.04 LTS is a *flavor* and thus only came with 3 years of supported life.  You can use `ubuntu-security-status` to view the status of what packages came with 3 years support (ie. those from 'universe' including all *flavors*), and those with 5 years of years of *standard* support (which include packages found on Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) or Ubuntu Cloud).  Read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu and it'll tell you "*Kubuntu 20.04 LTS will be supported for 3 years until April 2023.*"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LTS support for Kubuntu vs Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393895/lts-support-for-kubuntu-vs-ubuntu)

Comment: Just FYI:  If you're not familiar with `ubuntu-support-status`, `ubuntu-security-status` etc... I gave an example [here when I posted the EOL warning for Lubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-20-04-lts-is-nearing-its-eol-end-of-life/4087).  Kubuntu & other *flavors* of Ubuntu (*for the most part*) posted similar warnings too.  If you want to know the *supported life* of your OS, use the official notices, release announcements & don't trust 3rd party *bloggers* etc. unless you verify their details as well. If you read the post you provided; it applied to Ubuntu (not Kubuntu)

Comment: You may want to fix the title and have the correct OS version.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Kubuntu 20.04 Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu):

> Support lifespan
>
> Kubuntu 20.04 LTS will be supported for 3 years until April 2023.

Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server have 5-year support for LTS releases.
The many other excellent flavors (including Kubuntu) have 3-year support for LTS releases.